# IIS Manager is working but Window is not showing up in Windows 7

Tags: windows, iis-7

IIS Manager window is not showing in my machine. It is visible in taskbar but when I click on it, it is not opening or showing up. It was working previously, but stopped suddenly.

My system Details are:

- Windows 7 64 bit
- IIS Manager version 7.5

Comment: Can you type inetmgr from command line ?

Answer (score 371):

This worked for me and it's easy..

1. Hover over IIS taskbar icon.
2. Right click on miniature popup.
3. Click on Maximize.

Comment: :( something so simple took an hour to find people were recommending a Windows reinstall. Thank you!!

Comment: incredible, why was it even like this in the first place lol.

Comment: 9 years and this isn't fixed...

Answer (score 245):

In a command prompt:
`C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Inetmgr.exe /reset`

This problem occurs when I open IIS Manager and when I have two monitors, and then later try to open it again over RDP with only one monitor. Using this reset command fixes it for me.

This works on RDP sessions which do not preview the window from the taskbar and thus cannot perform Abhijeet's steps.

Comment: Also works for ConnectWise ScreenConnect/Control
Many thanks man

Comment: This just saved me. I had reverted my web.config in source control and that lost some settings in IIS that I couldn't open to fix. Thank you very much!

Comment: Brilliant. Same situation, I had RDP in multi-monitor situation.

Answer (score 5):

It should be in `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv`.

If its not there go to

```
control panel -> programs -> Turn Windows Feature on/Off...
```

Then you will see a list of features, IIS should be one of them. If you expand the selection there is an option to turn Management tools on and off.

IIS Management Console should be checked.

OR

Open the Command Prompt and type `Iisreset /noforce`

If this errors out IIS wasnt installed correctly or was not installed at all.

Try this reference : [IIS Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1038)

Comment: It is there in C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv.. it is opening also and working also..but it is showing only in taskbar..window is not showing..

Comment: Hey @VaibhavJain , it worked amazingly perfect, Very much Thankful to you. I found it after a day :-)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue with my iismngr.

But I didn't had the "move" button available, I clicked on "Extend" and the windows showed up.

Feel so dumb...